# entry_submission_ready Hook Not Working

Tags: hook

I have created an extension to manipulate saved data when an entry is saved. I can't get this to work using entry_submission hooks, I cannot find that much information about this online. I believe I need to use entry_submission_ready.

Does anyone know why this does not work when I save an entry?

```
function entry_submission_ready($entry_id, $meta, $data)
{
    $data['field_id_123'] = 'Test';

    if(isset($this->EE->api_sc_channel_entries))
    {
        $this->EE->api_sc_channel_entries->data = $data;                    
    }
    else
    {
        $this->EE->api_channel_entries->data = $data;
    }
}
```

The hook IS being called because I can output $data to the screen (print_r) and can see the value of the field I have set in the $data array. But this is not saved to the entry.

I have also tried $this->EE->api_channel_entries->data['revision_post'] and entry_submission_ready. None work.

EE 2.7.2

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

I got it working.... silly, silly, silly me....

Initially I used entry_submission_end($entry_id, $meta, $data), but realised I needed entry_submission_ready.

I overlooked the fact entry_submission_ready uses different arguments, its ($meta, $data, $autosave) and not ($entry_id, $meta, $data)!

Now it works fine with the correct arguments. RTFM!